# Fast loading and display of images in python (Utilizing Libjpeg Turbo in Python?)

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I am currently creating an image viewer in python using Tkinter and PIL, but I want the image loading to be quicker. Therefore I would like to know how I could install and utilize Libjpeg Turbo with Tkinter and PIL, or even if I should use a different GUI toolkit like pyQT or a different imaging library (I found something called OpenCV?).

So essentially what is the best and fastest way I can load, resize, and display a large image in python?

EDIT: 
I believe the main bottleneck is image resizing, it is visible, but before that it is the image loading itself. I can not tell for sure though because I don't know how to measure such a thing as I am essentially a python newb.

And what I am doing is basically a minimalistic image viewer. If you want to see my code it is here: http://pastebin.com/fwf8b0cU

EDIT 2: I have run through cProfile a bunch and have fixed some code, and fixed some slowness. So now my question is essentially should I be using another GUI toolkit like pyQT or a different imaging library (I found something called OpenCV?).

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual bottleneck is? Have you measured your code to see which function is the slow one?

Comment: ^^ That and describe what you are trying to do a little more :P QT might be overkill for image viewing in python, but its great for GUI stuff! (I use it a lot).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to narrow down the source of the bottleneck I would start with some calls to [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) on your various sections of code. If that doesn't help or seems like too much effort, have a look into [Python Profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html)

Comment: I just tried using timeit, but I am having some troubles because it is all class oriented, problems with self and such :/

Comment: Try the profiling then or break out the image processing bits from the GUI stuff and test it in isolation. That would at least give you an idea of how much time it's taking to resize the images.

Comment: I would strongly suggest cProfile/pstats. timeit doesn't give enough granularity.

Comment: Thanks, ran it through cProfile. Updated post.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look on [PyTurboJPEG](https://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG) which is a Python wrapper of [libjpeg-turbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo) with insanely fast rescaling (1/2, 1/4, 1/8) while decoding large JPEG image.

```
from turbojpeg import TurboJPEG

# specifying library path explicitly
# jpeg = TurboJPEG(r'D:\turbojpeg.dll')
# jpeg = TurboJPEG('/usr/lib64/libturbojpeg.so')
# jpeg = TurboJPEG('/usr/local/lib/libturbojpeg.dylib')

# using default library installation
jpeg = TurboJPEG()

# direct rescaling 1/2 while decoding input.jpg to BGR array
in_file = open('input.jpg', 'rb')
bgr_array_half = jpeg.decode(in_file.read(), scaling_factor=(1, 2))
in_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the answers here do not cover using it with PIL

The thread below explains a lot more, but the short version is:

```
conda uninstall -y --force pillow pil jpeg libtiff libjpeg-turbo
pip   uninstall -y         pillow pil jpeg libtiff libjpeg-turbo
conda install -yc conda-forge libjpeg-turbo
CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -mavx2" pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: --compile pillow-simd
conda install -y jpeg libtiff
```

From: https://docs.fast.ai/performance.html#faster-image-processing

It only seems to work on Linux though. On MacOS X the Pillow-SIMD build doesn't seem to link to the libjpeg-turbo library properly.

Anyway, once compiled locally, pillow-simd replaces PIL and you get the acceleration of libjpeg-turbo and simd